# How to load a resource layout into the code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout, defined using xml.
I would like to reuse it. Thus, I need to load it in the code.
I have found `getResoruces().getLayout(R.layout.my_layout)` but it returns an `XmlResourceParser` object.
How can I convert it into a Linear Layout, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html). It should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Give an **ID** to your linearlayout from XML then use below code.

```
LinearLayout myLinLay=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
```

Comment: Ok, but the my layout is not in the ui yet.